# Linux tree command implementation in C

Tags: c, linux, tree

This is not a duplicate, i need to implement the tree program in C, but on Stack Overflow i find only implementations in which the indentation is made of only spaces and they don't print the pipe character while walking into subdirectories

[image]

How can i print the pipes and the spaces even if in subtirectories i have a different level of indentation?
And also, how can i know when i reach the last file so that i print the ` character instead of a pipe?

Comment: You probably need a function `void indent(int levels);` that does `printf("|           ");` about `levels` number of times. Call it and then display the file name.

Comment: At the point where you descend into a subdirectory, you know what the leading part of the indentation should be for everything in that subtree.  Pass that as an argument.

Comment: I cannot read the screen shot. Please post test as text.

Comment: "*find only implementations* I assume the assignment is *not* to find a solution in the internet, but to make up one yourself, right?

Comment: People will be more likely to post an answer if you share what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

The rules are:

- Do not use any indentation for the root (or base) directory.
- Starting at the eldest parent, down to parent, check if a parent directory is the last item in its own parent directory.
  For those that are, use  for its indentation; otherwise, use `│`.
- If the current item is the last item in parent directory, use `└─` to indent it; otherwise, use `├─`.

In practice, you need to scan (and remember) the contents of a directory, before descending to any of its subdirectories.

---

If you do this recursively, you can use a single, dynamically allocated buffer for the indentation; it contains the vertical bars and spaces for the parent directories. The final item (with the horizontal bar) is printed separately. When you do a recursive call to print the contents of a subdirectory, first append either a space or a vertical bar to the indentation string (depending on whether the subdirectory is the last item in the current directory or not). After the recursive call, trim the indentation string back to its original length.

Note that you will have to store the names of items in a directory in an array or a linked list, because you need them all before recursing into any subdirectory.  If you do not do that, you cannot know whether an item is the last one in its directory or not, and you cannot do the output correctly. You must keep the names dynamically, without any count or length limits, because there are no such limits in practice. (Even if there are some limits on some machines, they depend on the file system used, and are not really discoverable except by exceeding them.)

A test implementation I wrote, using [`nftw()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html) to construct a full tree structure first, and then printing it out, was about 300 lines long, including all error checks. No, I will not post it, because it would be misused by nefarious students, passed as their own work.